# How to keep a specif column based on row conditions?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, if-statement, pythonanywhere

Does someone knows how to get the next followed structure in Pandas?

I have a Pandas data frame that looks like this

```
ID  Con  Case   VAR3  VAR4  VAR5

1    TT    TG    .01  .09   .90
2    CC    TC    .20  .34   .56
3    GG    AG    .10  .20   .70
4    TC    TC    .17  .48   .35
5    AG    AG    .12  .46   .32
6    GG    TG    .15  .20   .65
7    TT    TC    .06  .24   .70
8    TT    CT    .11  .21   .68 
9    GT    GT    .05  .10   .85
```

1. If the first 'letter' in [VAR2] (e.g T) it is doubled in [VAR1] (e.g. TT) -> take value from VAR3 (.01).
2. If the combination of the letters in [VAR2] (e.g. TC) it is the same as in [VAR1] (e.g. TC) -> take value from VAR4 (.48).
3. If the second 'letter' in [VAR2] (e.g G) it is doubled in [VAR1] (e.g GG) -> take value from VAR5 (.70).

Based on this information I would like my output data frame to look as follow:

```
ID  VAR1  VAR2   VAR6 

1    TT    TG    .01
2    CC    TC    .56
3    GG    AG    .70
4    TC    TC    .48
5    AG    AG    .46
6    GG    TG    .65
7    TT    TC    .06
8    TT    CT    .68
9    GT    GT    .10
```

Hopefully someone can give me a hint!

Thanks,

Ale.

Comment: What have you tried to do so far? There are many ways to manipulate columns and conditions in pandas, have you looked into those?

Comment: Hello, I have tried with np.where this is that I have done so far is this df['var7'] = np.where((df['VAR1'] == 'AA') & ((df['VAR2'] == 'AG') | (df['VAR2'] == 'AC')), df['VAR3'],0) per each combination (20), because the order matters, is there any possibility much easier than this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly, I'd first write a function that will evaluate your conditions and return the desired value:

```
def classify(item):
    if item["VAR1"] == item["VAR2"][0]*2:
        return item["VAR3"]
    if item["VAR1"] == item["VAR2"]:
        return item["VAR4"]
    if item["VAR1"] == item["VAR2"][1]*2:
        return item["VAR5"]
    return 0  # what if none is true?
```

Then apply it to your dataframe, specifying the new column:

```
df["VAR6"] = df.apply(classify, axis=1)

# You can also drop the middle columns if needed
df.drop(["VAR3", "VAR4", "VAR5"], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Output:

```
   VAR1 VAR2  VAR6
ID                
1    TT   TG  0.01
2    CC   TC  0.56
3    GG   AG  0.70
4    TC   TC  0.48
5    AG   AG  0.46
6    GG   TG  0.65
7    TT   TC  0.06
8    TT   CT  0.68
9    GT   GT  0.10
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works perfectly, because I was doing each combination using np.where.